# Assigning an animation to multiple objects in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, storyboard

I'll go directly to the problem. In my code, there is an array of Ellipses, namely
        `Ellipse[] players = new Ellipse[11];`
and then, I use DoubleAnimationWithKeyFrames to animate these ellipses in a canvas, using

```
sboard.Children.Add(anim);
sboard.Children.Add(anim2);
Storyboard.SetTargetName(anim, players[player - 1].Name);
Storyboard.SetTargetName(anim2, players[player - 1].Name);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(anim, new PropertyPath(Canvas.LeftProperty));
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(anim2, new PropertyPath(Canvas.TopProperty));
```

But I want to move some TextBlocks with these Ellipses. How can I assign the same anim and anim2 to these TextBlocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the Ellipse and TextBlock in a container (grid, stackpanel, canvas, etc.) or make a UserControl, and animate that instead of the Ellipse.

Example:

```
<UserControl
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
x:Class="WpfApplication4.UserControl1"
x:Name="UserControl">

<StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Ellipse Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Height="100" Stroke="Black" Width="100"/>
    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Some Text Here" FontSize="32" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
</StackPanel></UserControl>
```